# The state of the current PowerShell instance is not valid for this operation

Tags: c#, powershell

I have created a powershell instance as below and ran a powershell script which is called multiple times from my C# application. It works fine for some time but after some time I get the error as "The state of the current PowerShell instance is not valid for this operation."

How can I avoid this?

```
class DataRulesPSScripts
    {
        private static PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
        private static PowerShell PsInstance
        {
            get
            {
                if( ps == null )
                {
                    ps = PowerShell.Create();
                }
                return ps;
            }
        }
        public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> CreateAndRunScriptBlock(
            string pSScript, Dictionary<string, object> scriptParameters )
        {
            PsInstance.AddScript( pSScript );
            var scriptBlock = (await PsInstance.InvokeAsync())[0].BaseObject as ScriptBlock;
            var vars = scriptParameters.Select( p => new PSVariable( p.Key, p.Value ) ).ToList();
            return scriptBlock.InvokeWithContext( null, vars );
        }
    }    
}
```

the CreateAndRunScriptBlock() method is called from an internal method defined in a different class

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<object>> GenerateValuesFromScript( Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> arg, string pwScript )
        {
            var pars = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            pars.Add( "_", arg );
            return (await ds.CreateAndRunScriptBlock( pwScript, pars )).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: My two cents: If you get a `InvalidPowerShellStateException`, check its `CurrentState` property value. It will help you find the root cause. My guess is that as `AddScript` **is not thread safe**,  you'll get this exception if there is still a _running_ script at the time you try to add another script.

Comment: You keep adding the same script to existing instance...

Comment: so how do I fix this?